# How to setup the environment for Angular 2.0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

Taking my initial steps towards Angular 2.0.

First thing is to set up the right environment for the development.

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome to Angular 2.0</title>
  <!--css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="container">
    <h1> Hello Angular 2 </h1>
      <my-app> Loading app component....<my-app>
</div>
<!--js-->
<!-- Polyfills for older browsers -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.8"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js">   </script>

<script> window.autoBootstrap = true; </script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (e) { console.log(e); });
  </script>
  <!--js-->
 </body>

 </html>
```

I have copied the content from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html for the following files:-

- app.component.ts
- app.module.ts
- main.ts

NPM is installed & running.

[image: NodeJS]

But in order to get the `node_modules` folders with the required dependencies for the app to run. 
What commands do I need to run.

> What are the commands that I need to run to set up the Angular 2 environment?

Please note I am new to NPM.
Thanks.

Comment: @echonax, please note I am new to NPM

Comment: Just follow the angular docs. That is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` in the root project (it will create your `node_modules` from the dependencies mentioned in `package.json` file, should have [those files](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) as a start)

Comment: my app is located at  D:\Workspace\Angular\Lab1\app

Comment: So you should point on it with the `cd <path>` command, then run `npm install` to get your *node_modules* directory.

Comment: normally you should do in you command prompt:
`d:` , then `cd \Workspace\Angular\Lab1\app` , then `npm i`

Comment: Don't you think we need to have package.json??

Answer (score 2):

You have **angular-cli** wich is a good starter point. It will set you everything up according to best practices.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to set up your first Angular 2 Application.

1. Download the zip version here.**[firstAngular2App](https://github.com/aravindfz/firstAngular2App)**
2. Extract it to your destination folder. `Assume D:`
3. Open your command prompt(ensure that all required softwares are installed).
4. Navigate it to the folder. Use the command `cd D:\firstAngular2App`
5. Executre `npm install`
6. Once it is done use `npm start`

This way you have your first Angular2 appliction up and running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as an IDE, you may want to explore [how they recommend setting up Angular](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial).  I personally found their  installation guide painless and feature-rich.  I have never walked through an official Angular installation before due to being drenched in jQuery projects.  This guide was simple enough to give me a good beginners understanding.