# Error When Run *npm run install -AOT compiles*

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, angular2-aot

i'm new in Angular 2.0

i download project from git.

prerequisites for run the project are these steps :

1) npm install && bower install

2) npm run install-application

-AOT compiles
   -Tree shakes 
   -Bundles app into single file

2) npm run start

i do all of steps Except *-AOT compilies*.

when i run *npm install -AOT compiles* i get above error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsA6J.png)

Comment: Can you post the git project url?

Comment: is it your first Angular2 app if so have a look at my answer here in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569920/how-to-setup-the-environment-for-angular-2-0/41570168#41570168

Comment: Thanks @hackerman.git url : https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples

Comment: @abotalebhashemi wast it helpful or you want to fix on the package which you are specifying.

Comment: @ Aravind   yes. i'm new in Angular2 but i made Hello world sample .now i want to run Advanced git project that i say in last comment

Comment: Based on the documentation you just need to run `npm run install-application`

Comment: With `AOT compiles`, they are referring to `Ahead Of Time` compilation, a new angular2 feature, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html