# How do I install Angular 2 using NPM?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to setup my own local development environment for an Angular 2 app without using the QuickStart seed mentioned in the Angular 2 [site](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) or the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) because they tend to come with extra files that I don't really require.

Now, everything's going fine except that I don't know how to get Angular 2 using NPM. I've tried using `npm install angular2 --save` but I just found out that angular2 has been deprecated and was a pre-release version. So I guess how do I get the latest Angular 2.0 plugins using NPM, if at all possible at the moment?

Comment: Did you try the stackoverflow documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2#t=20170121174015002968

Answer (score 5):

at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html, is recommended to use QuickStart seed, here is its [package.json](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json), so actually we need to download its dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

  "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
  "systemjs": "0.19.40",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "5.0.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
}
```

you could also create your custom **package.json**, by running `npm init`, copying these dependencies (or most of them) and than running `npm install` with your package.json

Answer (score 3):

**Angular 4** could be installed in two ways:

> *Note: Make sure your system already installed node js and npm*

1. Perform the clone-to-launch steps with terminal commands.
2. [Download](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip) the QuickStart seed and unzip it into your project folder. Then perform the steps mentioned later with terminal commands.

**1. Cloning :**

Suppose you want to make a project named helloworld, then run the following commands from your terminal

```
 git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git helloworld
 cd helloworld
 npm install
 npm start
```

After running last command you could see from your browser like this

[image]

**2. Downloading :**

[Download](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip) the QuickStart seed and unzip it into your project folder. Then perform the below steps with terminal commands.

```
cd quickstart
npm install
npm start
```

For more details go to [official site](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html)

Answer (score 2):

1. Paste the below code into a file by creating and naming it as
   **package.json**.

   ```
   {
   "name": "demo-app",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "author": "Aravind",
   "description": "set up files for the first Demo App",
   "scripts": {
       "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
       "tsc": "tsc",
       "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
       "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
       "lite": "lite-server",
       "typings": "typings",
       "postinstall": "typings install"
   },
   "license": "ISC",
       "dependencies": {
       "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
       "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
       "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
       "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
       "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
       "@angular/router": "3.0.0",

       "core-js": "^2.4.1",
       "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
       "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
       "systemjs": "0.19.27",
       "zone.js": "^0.6.23",

       "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
       "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
       "tslint": "^3.7.4",
       "typescript": "^2.0.2",
       "typings": "^1.0.4"
   },
   "repository": {}
   }
   ```
2. navigate to the root folder in Cmd and

   ```
   npm install 

   or

   npm i
   ```

Alternatively if you want to create a new **package.json**

1. Navigate to a folder in command prompt
2. Execute the command

   ```
   npm init
   ```
3. This will create a new **package.json** file and copy paste the above code to install angular2 along with few other basic dependencies.

If you are looking for a simple set up. Have a look at this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569920/how-to-setup-the-environment-for-angular-2-0/41570168#41570168)**.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on your build tool, if it is webpack, you need just install angular components, like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0"
}
```

And all additional vendor modules if it needed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Angular CLI 1.1.3
2. Uninstall latest version of CLI > `npm uninstall –g @angular/cli`
3. Clean the Cache >`npm cache clean`
4. Install the Specific version of angular CLI > `npm install –g @angular/cli@1.1.3`
5. Open the Node js Command prompt.
6. Navigate to Project folder location  >`cd project_name`
7. Install below mentioned packages,
8. `npm i codemirror`
9. `npm i ng2-codemirror`
10. `npm i ng2-split-pane`
11. `npm i ng2-daterange-picker`
12. Run the `npm install`
13. Finally do > `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

**Installing Angular Dependencies**

- Install a stable version of [Node](https://nodejs.org/) (if not already installed) and verify the installation using `node -v`
- Install [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) using [command `npm install -g typescript`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links)
- Download and install [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) using command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

`Angular` is a component oriented framework. Many components needs to be created to make the whole application. A component is a group of [custom elements, `HTML` elements, `ShadowDOM` & `HTML` imports.](//xameeramir.github.io/Custom-Elements-Shadow-DOM-Templates-in-HTML-by-Examples/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download example from https://angular.io/
2. Save this code and rename it.
3. Navigate to the root folder in Cmd.

   ```
   $ cd myproject
   ```
4. Execute the command

   ```
   $ npm install
   $ npm start
   ```