# Angular 2: npm start not working?

Tags: node.js, angular

I downloaded an Angular 2 example from the official website, ran npm install, then npm start.
But npm start is giving me error. 
I am using windows powershell (because ubuntu doesn't let me update to npm 4.3.0).
I have typescript version 2.2.1,
npm version 4.4.0,
node version 7.7.1.
This is the error I am getting
Any help is appreciated

```
src/app/header.component.ts(5,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/header.component.ts(5,33): error TS1002: Unterminated string literal.
src/app/header.component.ts(7,1): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/header.component.ts(8,20): error TS1005: '{' expected.
src/app/header.component.ts(8,22): error TS1005: '=>' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(5,32): error TS1002: Unterminated string literal.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(6,6): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(7,15): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal
src/app/prescription.components.ts(8,17): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal
src/app/prescription.components.ts(9,16): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal
src/app/prescription.components.ts(10,4): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal
src/app/prescription.components.ts(11,19): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(11,40): error TS1005: '{' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(11,55): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(12,10): error TS1005: '>' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(12,13): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(12,25): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(13,8): error TS1005: '>' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(13,14): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(13,35): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,9): error TS1005: '>' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,24): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,31): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,33): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,38): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,44): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,46): error TS1110: Type expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(14,47): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression litera
src/app/prescription.components.ts(15,9): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(15,33): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(15,38): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(15,46): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(15,48): error TS1110: Type expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(15,49): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression litera
src/app/prescription.components.ts(16,9): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(16,33): error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(16,38): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(16,45): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(16,47): error TS1110: Type expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(16,48): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression litera
src/app/prescription.components.ts(17,6): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal
src/app/prescription.components.ts(18,5): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal
src/app/prescription.components.ts(19,1): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(30,26): error TS1005: '{' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(31,6): error TS1005: ':' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(31,37): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/prescription.components.ts(32,25): error TS1005: ',' expected.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc -p src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Reimu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-03-04T20_10_10_067Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Reimu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-03-04T20_10_10_213Z-debug.log
```

UPDATE: package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: update your post with package.json file

Comment: did you use this one ? https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569920/how-to-setup-the-environment-for-angular-2-0/41570168#41570168)

Comment: @Aravind added the json

Comment: Just tried with powershell and node 7.5 and works fine.

Comment: `npm start fails in Bash for Windows which does not support networking to servers as of January, 2017.` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

Comment: Yes I have ran npm install, then npm start, but then npm start is giving me the error above

Comment: @Pear did u try the starter files using my answer in the above comment?

Comment: can you share, wether `prescription.components.ts` or `header.components.ts`

Answer (score 1):

If you really try

```
npm install
npm build
npm start
```

and this message still appear, could you please tell us what is the last thing you wrote in your type script files.

Did you really get the code from [here](http://github.com/angular/quickstart) ? If yes, I did the following from node.js command prompt and worked as magic:

```
cd C:\..<your path>
npm install
npm build
npm start
```

[image]

Comment: yeah I clone'd, cd'd installed, then started, didn't work

Comment: Could you please share with me the header.component.ts  and prescription.components.ts codes as they are not included in quickstart folder.

Comment: Oh, now that you mentioned it I realized what I have done wrong. Thank you so much